# Implementing comet pattern with Tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, comet, long-polling

I just learned about comet pattern(Long polling) and very curious to implement a simple example with Tomcat6 as container.
What i am trying to do here is - I am going to call a servlet that generates a random number between 1 and 20 and based on that random number it should waits that number of seconds before responding to client.

For Example : if generated random number is 10 , then the servlet should wait 10 seconds before it send response.

Here is my servlet that implements `CometProcessor`

```
public class RandomNumberGenerator extends HttpServlet implements CometProcessor {
```

doPost method :

```
        PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomInt = r.nextInt(20) + 1;
        out.print(randomInt);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Now, as i implemented `CometProcessor` I've got an event method :

```
@Override
    public void event(CometEvent event) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }
```

What i can't figure out is that, what Iv'e to do with this `event` method to do what i want.

What i know here is, their will be some events i can handle inside this method like : `BRGIN,READ,END,ERROR`

Should i use events like this ?

```
if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN) {
    event.setTimeout(numberOfSecondToWait);
}
```

I am totally confused as [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/) tutorial seem a bit complex to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently wrote a blog post on [WebSockets and Comet](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2012/04/22/websockets-realise-comet-theyre-not-an-alternative.html) and asked the inventor of 'Comet' to provide his opinion.

In summary, Alex said [WebSockets replace Comet](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2012/04/22/websockets-realise-comet-theyre-not-an-alternative.html#comment-518850026).

So, although people are still using Comet it will ultimately be replaced with WebSockets since they were specifically created to solve a problem that Comet solutions hacked around.

I'd recommend you shift your focus to WebSockets.

Comment: do all browsers support WebSockets ?

Comment: The current state of play with browser support can be seen here: http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets The standard practice when WebSockets aren't available is to use the [web-socket-js polyfill](https://github.com/pusher/web-socket-js). For older browsers you can look at Comet-based fallbacks or simply drop to standard polling. The latter isn't ideal but it's probably the way I would go - or progressively enhance my app and if the browser doesn't support WebSockets then the user would get reduced functionality.

Comment: today i implemented comet using DWR and it is working as expected `:)` . Well,  I'll definitely try web-sockets as it seems very interesting. Thanks you !